# Unit testing a service, which works as a mediator between two other services

Tags: java, unit-testing, testing, junit

I have a service, which works as a mediator between two other services. It basically validates the inputs, then passes them to those two service sequentially (by trying to keep transactional integrity), and then, if everything goes well, saves a result to the database.

My problem now is to test this service in isolation. Of course, I can provide stubs to satisfy the dependencies. I can also test the validation of inputs, whether appropriate data is saved in the DB in a normal case, as well as whether transactional integrity is kept if any of the dependencies throws an exception.

Yet, this is only half of what the service really does. My dilemma is if I should try to prove whether the other two dependency services actually processed the data appropriately as well? The scope of my service is quite broad, so I guess it is better to also know if the dependency services also did their job well. Yet, this gets out of the scope unit testing, and moves into integration testing, right?

I am kind of confused here.

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking about unit-testing, then the way to do it is to test the class in isolation using mocks or stubs.

BUT, if you feel that just doing that is not enough, you can write some *component* tests, where you use the all the real classes you want to test, and use a stub (or inmemory) database and mock some of the dependencies that you consider not important for what you are trying to test.

In the past, I've tested small clusters of classes that had a high interaction between them in this way (and sometimes skipping unit-tests for those classes, as the component tests covered all the scenarios). Obviously, the problem with doing this is that the number of scenarios grows almost exponentially the more classes you're testing. Maybe you can test the bridge and the 2 real classes that use that bridge.

Answer (score 0):

You should do both.

For unit testing, definitely use mock-objects for dependencies, preferrably using a tool like [EasyMock](http://easymock.org/). As a sidenote, if you feel that the functionality of your mediator service is too broad for unit testing, you may want to consider breaking it down into smaller pieces.

Of course, you additionally should do integration testing as well, using real dependencies, to make sure your services work together as intended.